# Показ изображения только при первом заходе на страницу

Tags: javascript, cookie, php, settimeout

По сути, в заголовке отразил основную тематику обращения) Как пример, пользователь заходит первый раз на страницу и видит изображение, при повторном заходе на страницу он этого изображения видеть не должен!

Comment: По сути, вы не только отразили суть вопроса в заголовке, но и в тегах указали то, что понадобиться для решения вашего вопроса. В чем же проблема?

Comment: есть еще local storage, чтоб не хранить кучу данных на сервере.

Comment: Проблема в том, что идея есть. Хочу исполнить! Не знаю от чего оттолкнуться. Прописывал в гугле javascript setTimes, javascript visible, javascript cookie. Понимаю, что мне нужно что-то из этого, но как использовать умом не дойду(

Comment: Вот вам [простой примерчик][1]. При первом заходе, вы будете видеть картинку, при всех последующих заходах - нет. По такой же аналогии, можно сделать и с куками.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/HFVPM/

Comment: у вас там в тэге php
в сессию записывайте флаг
типа

    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['visited'])) {
        show_image(); //показываем картинку
        $_SESSION['visited']=true;
    }

Comment: @eicto почему ты любишь ответ писать не в ответы, а в комментарии )

Comment: не считаю это достойным ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, eicto) Но как это можно присобачить к моему индех.пхп? 

<?php
/**
 * Template for Joomla by VG
 * @author Viktor Goryachev
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2013, www.monckey.ru
 * @license    GNU GPL
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <jdoc:include type="head" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/style.css"/>
 </head>
 
 <body>
    ...
</body>
</html>

Comment: ну а где у вас картинка-то выводится ? вот там и проверяйте наличие флага.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю решить так:

*CSS:*

```
#first { display: none; }
```

*HTML:*

```
<img id="first" src="any/path.jpg" alt="Show once" />
```

*JS:*

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
if (document.cookie.length>0)
 {
 c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
 if (c_start!=-1)
   {
  return true;
   }
 }
return false;
}

var showIt = getCookie('show');
if (!showIt) {
   document.getElementById('first').style.display='block';
   document.cookie='show=true; path=/; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT';
}
```

P.S> Не проверял, но должно работать. Мб есть способ легче с использование jQuery,  использование php и сессий для таких задач, по моему мнению не очень корректно.

Comment: Ребята, всем огромное спасибо за помощь! Олег! Вы гений! Прошу, последнее, что хочу от вас, расскажите, как лучше начать осваивать javascript? Как вы добились таких познаний?!

Comment: Спасибо за комплимент! На самом деле я не так хорошо знаю JS как кажется ;) Насчет осваивания к сожалению ничего подсказать не смогу тк самоучка, тут много писали про книги, поищите уверен много толкового. Удачи вам!

Comment: Спасибо!) Всего доброго)))

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи, вопрос не исчерпан, к сожалению. Прежде, при первых запусках код работал, но теперь картинка просто не появляется при заходе с других пк, пока она в связке со скриптом Олега(

Comment: @viboxjuwin, этого не может быть! Неужели другой ПК использует куки вашего компьютера? По воздуху, что ли?